# ndarrayオブジェクトのin演算子による存在判定のエラーについて

Tags: python, numpy

エラーの回避はどうしたらいいでしょうか？
ndarray以外のオブジェクトに関してもリストで管理して、リストになければ登録するという実装を他にもしていています。これだけ例外にしなくてはいけなくて萎えています。
具体的には以下のような利用をしています。

```
if not(obj in objList):
    objList.append(obj)
```

現状はUserListを継承したクラスでappendメソッドをオーバーライドする方向で考えています。
コードを書き直す元気がでないので、エラーについての解説や回避方法や実装方法についてアドバイスあれば助かります。

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array([1,2])
c = a
d = [a,b,c]
print(a in d) #->True
print(b in d) #->Error
# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
print(c in d) #->True
```

Comment: `b in np.array(d)`

Comment: 「等値判定」ではなく、「存在判定」であれば `id(b) in map(id, d)` の方がよいでしょう。

Comment: idで判定する方法があるんですね。
map関数も使用したことがなかったので調べてみようと思います。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントにある対応方法の他にも、[類似質問の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/39224/9820)のように`(b==d).all(axis=1).any()`と記述することで回避できます。
上のリンク先は`np.array`の二次元配列ですが、組み込みのlist型でも同様に対応可能です。

なお、`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`エラーの原因は英語でambiguousと書かれているように、判定の条件があいまいだからです。

公式ドキュメントの[帰属検査演算](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.6/reference/expressions.html#in)には下記の記述があります。

> 式 `x in y` は `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`と等価です。

上の通りに`any(b is x or b == x for x in d)`と記述しても`b == x`でエラーとなります。
numpyの仕様として、組み込みのlist型に対して上記の比較を行った際にはわざとエラーを発生させているようです。

参考資料：
[numpyやpandasでThe truth value of ... is ambiguous.のようなエラーが出たときの対処](https://www.haya-programming.com/entry/2019/03/15/235259)

Comment: 早速回答いただきありがとうございました。
やはり内部ではis と=両方で比較がされていたんですね。
今度から質問の前に公式ドキュメントを参照しようと思います。
def has_X(self,X):
    return any(X is e for e in self)
 かあるいは最初にコメントいただいたmapでの対処にしようと思います。
内包表現的な記述がリスト以外でも使えるとは知りませんでした。